# The tiles of my scrolling tile-based platformer aren't loading onto the screen

Tags: python, image, pygame, tile

I've been working on this platformer for a couple months now and I've encountered a problem: when I try to load the tiles of my level, they don't show up. Plus, the game lags like hell when I try to *.blit()* the tiles. Using *.convert()* and *.convert_alpha()* helped but it didn't entirely remove it, or at least not enough to make the game playable. I've tried to make a seperate *for loop* to load the tiles one after then other right after updating their position, but it didn't change anything. I tried to use *.flip()* and *pygame.display.update()* after the *.blit()* funtion but in vain.

Here's the Tile class:

```
class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

                def __init__(self,pos,size):
                                super().__init__()
                                self.image = pygame.Surface((size,size))
                                self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
                                
                                
                def update(self,x_shift,y_shift,png,screen):
                                self.rect.x += x_shift
                                self.rect.y += round(y_shift)
                                screen.blit(png, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
```

The game loop (don't mind the messy code):

```
def run(self):
                                player = self.player.sprite
                                
                                if self.innit == "false":
                                                self.innit = "true"
                                                self.scroll_y_position = player.rect.y
                                if self.menu == "false":
                                                self.menu = "true"
                                                self.button = Button((200,200),"start")
                                                self.go = "no"
                                if self.go == "no":
                                                self.go = self.button.update_start()
                                                self.button.update(self.display_surface)

#Everything above this comment is just for the menu and the innit function, the real game loop is below this comment
                                
                                else:
                                                self.player.update()
                                                self.tiles.update(self.world_shiftx, self.world_shifty,self.tile_image,self.display_surface)

                                                self.dangers.update(self.world_shiftx, self.world_shifty)
                                                self.dangers.draw(self.display_surface)

                                                self.portals.update(self.world_shiftx, self.world_shifty)
                                                self.portals.draw(self.display_surface)
                        
                                                self.scroll_x()
                                                player.rect.x += player.direction.x * player.speed  
                                                self.horizontal_movement_collision()

                                                self.scroll_y()
                                                player.rect.y += player.direction.y + self.world_shifty
                                                self.vertical_movement_collision()

                                                self.player.draw(self.display_surface)
                                                self.scroll_y_position += player.direction.y - 0.8

                                                self.player_events()
```

And tile_image variable:

```
self.tile_image = pygame.image.load("/home/yzaques/Platformer/tile.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s. Likely your *Sprites* are drawn through [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). This method uses the `rect` and `image` attributes of the *Sprites* to draw them. Therefore, you need to change the `image` attribute instead of trying to `blit` the new bitmap:

```py
class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos,size):
        self.image = pygame.Surface((size,size))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)

    def update(self,x_shift,y_shift,png,screen):
        self.rect.x += x_shift
        self.rect.y += round(y_shift)
        self.image = png
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
```